# How to refer @IBAction Func to several button outlets

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton

I have lots of buttons that when pressed run very similar code, im currently writing a function for each, is there a way to compact this to one function?

Heres some of the code:

```
   @IBAction func b0(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if  pressedArray[0] && buttonsCanBePressed {
            pressedArray[0] = false
            b0.backgroundColor = notPressedColour
        } else if buttonsCanBePressed {
            b0.backgroundColor = pressedColour
            pressedArray[0] = true
        }
    }



    @IBAction func b1(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if  pressedArray[1] && buttonsCanBePressed {
            pressedArray[1] = false
            b1.backgroundColor = notPressedColour
        } else if buttonsCanBePressed {
            b1.backgroundColor = pressedColour
            pressedArray[1] = true
        }
    }

    @IBAction func b2(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if  pressedArray[2] && buttonsCanBePressed {
            pressedArray[2] = false
            b2.backgroundColor = notPressedColour
        } else if buttonsCanBePressed {
            b2.backgroundColor = pressedColour
            pressedArray[2] = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes there is. First of all think about this: the sender is the button.

Comment: Also what is the goal here? If you’re trying to write “radio” buttons there is a standard approach.

Comment: I worked it out - for easier than I realised - ill delete the question. Its hard to explain but its part of a game, there is underlying logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can make only one IBAction function, and then drag the circle in the line number to all the buttons you want, and you can differentiate the buttons using sender.tag

[image]